# Getting the names of unicode pictograms

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to analyse a text stream that includes unicode pictograms like these:

```
 -> 128132 -> Lipstick
 -> 128133 -> Nail Polish
 -> 128139 -> Kiss Mark
```

I'd like to be able to look up the name of each of these characters, so for example any time I encounter the  glyph I'd like to replace it with an alphanumeric symbol like "UNICODE_LIPSTICK".

Is there a data file somewhere that lists the numbers of all of the unicode characters and their names? I'm after some kind of mapping (preferably in a plain text format that's easily imported). Does such a data set exist?

I'm actually programming in Python 3, so if there's something built into the language that would do this, even better!

Comment: You know these are **emojis**, right? You may find that term more useful for googling.

Comment: [`unicodedata.name`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`unicodedata.name()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) to look up the official codepoint name:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(128132))
'LIPSTICK'
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(128133))
'NAIL POLISH'
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(128139))
'KISS MARK'
```